# Map the nesting of array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have this data:

```
const data = [
  {
    name: 'chase',
    advisors: [
      {
        name: 'mark',
        clients: [
          { name: 'carol', savings: 500, checking: 600 },
          { name: 'toby', savings: 500, checking: 300 },
          { name: 'nich' }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'holly',
        clients: [
          { name: 'john', savings: 900 },
          { name: 'jim', checking: 200 },
          { name: 'bruce', checking: 200 },
          { name: 'sarah', savings: 500, checking: 300 }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'citiBank',
    advisors: [
      {
        name: 'cindy',
        clients: [ { name: 'casey', savings: 500, checking: 200 } ]
      },
      { name: 'bob', clients: null }
    ]
  },
  { name: 'hsbc', advisors: null }
];
```

The output we have to get is an array of objects with that are ordered by greatest value of savings first, and if the savings value is the same, we have to order by the greatest checking value first.

Finally, the client array should look like this:

```
[{ name: 'john', savings: 900, firm:'chase',advisor:'holly' },{ name: 'carol', savings: 500, checking: 600, firm: 'chase', advisor: 'mark'},{ name: 'sarah', savings: 500, checking: 300 ,advisor:'holly',firm:'chase'},{ name: 'toby', savings: 500, checking: 300, firm:'chase',advisor:'mark', },{ name: 'casey', savings: 500, checking: 200,firm:'citi bank',advisor:'cindy' }....]
```

Below is the function defined

```
const maxSavingsData = ()=>{
  const client = [];
  console.log(client);
}
maxSavingsData(data);
```

Comment: What is the sort order when also checking is the same, like for Sarah and Toby?

Comment: it should be alphabetically based sarah should come first after that toby should come can you help me out by editing the answer

Comment: I have updated my answer to follow that requirement. It is a bit odd that it takes 7 weeks to answer a remark ;-)

Comment: @trincot i was suffering from a disease thats why i was completely out of it Anyway thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I would split this task into two phases:

1. First create the target objects in the order you get them from the source data;
2. Sort that array using the `sort` callback function.

Here is how that could work:

```js
const maxSavingsData = (data) => 
    data.flatMap(({name: firm, advisors}) =>
        (advisors ?? []).flatMap(({name: advisor, clients}) => 
            (clients ?? []).map(client => ({...client, firm, advisor}))
        )
    ).sort((a, b) => 
        (b.savings ?? 0) - (a.savings ?? 0) || 
        (b.checking ?? 0) - (a.checking ?? 0) ||
        a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
    );

const data = [{name: 'chase',advisors: [{name: 'mark',clients: [{ name: 'carol', savings: 500, checking: 600 },{ name: 'toby', savings: 500, checking: 300 },{ name: 'nich' }]},{name: 'holly',clients: [{ name: 'john', savings: 900 },{ name: 'jim', checking: 200 },{ name: 'bruce', checking: 200 },{ name: 'sarah', savings: 500, checking: 300 }]}]},{name: 'citiBank',advisors: [{name: 'cindy',clients: [ { name: 'casey', savings: 500, checking: 200 } ]},{ name: 'bob', clients: null }]},{ name: 'hsbc', advisors: null }];

const clients = maxSavingsData(data);
console.log(clients);
```